# Unable to access files using os functions

Tags: python, json, csv, os.path

I've been working to create a script that compares CSV files (based on this post: https://medium.com/@satsundev/compare-two-csv-using-python-92a0a23d7f54) but have run into an issue where Python can't locate the files I'm comparing. Below is the relevant portion of code I've been working on debugging.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import json
import sys

def check_file_permissions(file_path):
    if os.access(file_path, os.R_OK):
        print(f"Read permission is granted for file: {file_path}")
   
    else:
        print(f"Read permission is not granted for file: {file_path}")
    
    if os.access(file_path, os.W_OK):
        print(f"Write permission is granted for file: {file_path}")
   
    else:
        print(f"Write permission is not granted for file: {file_path}")
    
    if os.access(file_path, os.X_OK):
        print(f"Execute permission is granted for file: {file_path}")
   
    else:
        print(f"Execute permission is not granted for file: {file_path}")

cwd = os.getcwd()

cwwd = os.path.join(cwd, "Projects", "compare-csv")

input_JSON = os.path.join(cwwd, "data", "input.json")

input_data = json.load(open(input_JSON))

data = input_data ["info"]


for info in data:
    expected = os.path.join(cwwd, "inputs", "expected", info["expected"])
    actual = os.path.join(cwwd, "inputs", "actual", info["actual"])
    print (actual)
    
    # diff path
    diff = os.path.join(cwwd, "inputs", "diff", info["diff"])
    
    # summary path
    summary = os.path.join(cwwd, "inputs", "diff", info["summary"])
    
    # common identity column with unique value between two CSV files to compare
    identity = info["identity"]
    
    # os.chmod(actual, 777)
    
    check_file_permissions(actual)
    
    actual_path = os.path.exists(actual)
    print(actual_path)
```

For context, Print(actual) returns the correct path but print(actual_path) returns false.

If relevant, I am using JupyterLab and the Projects folder is located on my desktop. The JSON file is as follows:

```
{
    "info": [{
        "description": "Placeholder.",
        "expected": "user_info_expected.csv",
        "actual": "user_info_actual.csv",
        "diff": "user_info_diff.csv",
        "summary": "user_info_summary.csv",
        "identity": "id"
    }]
}
```

I looked into some of the documentation for os functions and found that os.path.exists() typically returns False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file. This is where I wrote check_file_permissions and when I ran it, it returns the negative for all three permissions.

From here, I started looking into os.chmod() which doesn't seem to do anything regardless of what level I try to grant permissions. Looking into my permissions, I have all the required permissions so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: `For context, Print(actual) returns the correct path but print(actual_path) returns false.` Are you sure the path exists? If you copy the path it prints out, and paste it into File Explorer, can it find the file?

Comment: What you're saying here is that there should be a file `Projects/compare-csv/inputs/expected/user_info_expected.csv`, starting from the working directory when you run the script (which is NOT the same as the directory that contains the script).  Are you sure that's so?  How are you running this?  From a terminal?  Prepending `cwd` to this is useless.  It always starts from the working directory.

Comment: @NickODell I just tried that and this what I get: 
`C:\Users\audreyjo.hembry\Desktop\Projects\compare-csv\Projects\compare-csv\inputs\actual\` 

but when I copy paste that into my file explorer Windows says that path doesn't exist. Which I'm just now realizing it recurs through Projects\compare-csv twice

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you're spot on. The path being returned should be: `C:\Users\audreyjo.hembry\Desktop\Projects\compare-csv\inputs\actual`
but is returning 
`C:\\Users\\audreyjo.hembry\\Desktop\\Projects\\compare-csv\\Projects\\compare-csv\\data\\input.json`
which is trying to pull Projects\compare-csv\ twice

Comment: Right.  That says you're already sitting in `compare-csv` when you run the script.  Perhaps you should use `os.environ['DESKTOP']` to get the base path to your desktop instead of using `getwd`.  Then it will work wherever you start.

Comment: @TimRoberts Okay I fixed that that issue and now it's directing to the right path. When I run Check_file_permissions(actual) and when I print(actual) I get the correct path. That said, if I run os.chmod(actual, 777) I get the message:
`[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\audreyjo.hembry\\Desktop\\Projects\\compare-csv\\inputs\\actual\\user_info_actual.csv`

Comment: Well, does that file actually exist?  And why are you doing that `chmod`?  If that's your desktop, then you have permission to read it.  `chmod` is not as useful in Windows as it is on Unix.

Comment: @TimRoberts It does. I can navigate to that file and if I copy+paste what it outputs I get the csv file I'm intending to open. I've got permission to access this file because I created it myself. `chmod` was my latest step in attempting to grant python permission to access this file (and subsequent files I'm attempting to manipulate). For whatever reason, `check_file_permissions(actual)` returns:
`Read permission is not granted for file: C:\Users\audreyjo.hembry\Desktop\Projects\compare-csv\inputs\actual\user_info_actual.csv`
Along with the same message for Write and Execute permissions

Comment: Are you running this as a scheduled task?  By default, that runs as a system user that doesn't have permission to your files.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'd like to eventually but not currently. Just running it via JupyterLab a la Anaconda

Comment: Are you running this on your local computer, or are you running this in a browser on a remote server?

Comment: @TimRoberts Local Computer. I've tried multiple IDEs at this time too so I can confirm it's not IDE specific. I've cleared my installs and reinstalled everything as well.

Comment: There has to be some simple disconnect.  If you start a command shell and do `type C:\Users\audreyjo.hembry\Desktop\Projects\compare-csv\inputs\actual\user_info_actual.csv`, do you see results?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think you've found the issue! When do what you suggested I get `The system cannot find the file specified`
From there I changed my directory to `C:\Users\audreyjo.hembry\Desktop\Projects\compare-csv\inputs\actual\` and then input `type user_info_actual.csv` and got the same exact error message. There is something fishy with how we're able to access files. I had two different coworkers try a similar test and they got the exact same errors as well. This seems to be an issue not with the PCs themselves. Thank you so so much for your help